# Why the divides relation on the set of positive integers antisymmetric

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, relations

I'd like to know why the divides relation  on the set of positive integers antisymmetric. The book says $a|b$ and $b|a$ then $a=b$. But I think if a|b and b not divides a for example $1|2$ but not $2|1$.

Comment: A related older question: [Is a dividing relation on the natural numbers an symmetric/antisymmetric relation?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2019982). (Very probably there are some other similar posts on this site.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The relation is antisymmetric if and only if for every $a, b$ in the set,

**IF** $(a\mid b$ AND $b\mid a)$, then it must follow that $a = b$.

If it's **NOT** true that both $a\mid b$ AND $b\mid a$, then it's perfectly consistent to have $a \neq b$.  Indeed, the only time $a \mid b$ AND $b\mid a$ is exactly when $a = b$, since then we have $a \mid b \iff a \mid a = \text{true for all a}$. Hence the relation is antisymmetric.

Antisymmetry here doesn't mean that it must hold that $a \mid b$ and $b\mid a$. It is true that to be *symmetric*, the relation must be such that *if* $a \mid b$, *then* $b\mid a$, too. So clearly, this relation is NOT *symmetric*.

But since $a \mid b$ and $ b\mid a$ is true if and only if $a = b$, then the relation satisfies the property of being ANTI-symmetric.

Comment: But I think it's false that a|b and b|a ,right?

Comment: It's true if and only if $a = b$. Take $a = b = 2$. Then $2\mid 2$ and $2\mid 2$. If $a\neq b$, then it may be that $a\mid b$, but not $b\mid a$, or else $b\mid a$ but not $a\mid b$, or else neither one divides the other.

Comment: Thank you but as I know if p then q is not equal if q then p

Comment: Antisymmetric: Let $p: a\mid b\; \land \; b\mid a$. Let $q: a = b$. Then a relation is antisymmetric if and only if $p \rightarrow q$. If $p$ happens to be false, that automatically makes $p\rightarrow q$ true, regardless of whether q is true or false, (hence in this case, true means antisymmetric). Recall that an implication is true whenever $p$ is false.

Comment: @amWhy: Needs another TU +1